# How to add a button or image to a ListView

Tags: c#, forms, listview

The goal is to have a scrollable list of entries wherein by clicking a button you would see more info about that entry. Is it even possible to insert functioning buttons inside a ListView?

Much thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you've done so far

Comment: We've inserted a ListView into a FlowLayoutPanel. We're able to make text entries but not clickable buttons.

Comment: ListViewItem inherits from object. Therefore you can't add any Controls to it. The best you can do with a ListView is to owner-draw all you want, including the Button and also code the Click actions. Maybe you ought to use a FLP and add UserControls to to, which contains what you need..

Comment: One of the reasons why `WPF` is superior to `Windows Forms`. Flexibility.